# I can't load data from delegate swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using delegates to pass data collected through JSON to several `UIViewControllers`.

[My setup is like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MA1c.png)

I create programaticaly the container for the `ContainedViewController` inside the `MainViewController`:

```
 func createContainer(){
      let controller: UIViewController = (storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("containedVC"))! as UIViewController
      controller.view.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: self.view.frame.height-220, width: self.view.frame.width-40, height: 200)
      view.addSubview(controller.view)
      self.addChildViewController(controller)
}
```

I call the function after I collect some data with JSON (**and pass them first on the MainViewController**) on another class and pass them to the `MainViewController`. The code I use for this purpose is:

```
func setForecast(forecast: Forecast) {
    self.delegateForecast?.loadOnContained(forecast)
    print("did forecast pass to delegate?")
    createContainer()
}
```

I've also set up a **protocol** on the `MainViewController`:

```
protocol dataForContainedDelegate{
    func loadOnContained(forecast: Forecast)
}
```

And a **variable**:

```
var delegateForecast: dataForContainedDelegate?
```

My code for the `containedVC` is:

```
import UIKit

class ContainedViewController: UIViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, dataForContainedDelegate {

    var forecastService = MainViewController()

    var pageViewController: UIPageViewController!
    var pageDates: NSArray!
    var pageHighTemps: NSArray!
    var pageLowTemps: NSArray!
    var pageDescriptions: NSArray!
    //var pageImages: NSArray!

    func loadOnContained(forecast: Forecast) {
        print("forecast loaded")
        self.pageDates = forecast.dates
        print("dates set")
        self.pageHighTemps = forecast.highTemps
        self.pageLowTemps = forecast.lowTemps
        self.pageDescriptions = forecast.descriptionsArray
        createVCs()
    }
    func createVCs(){
        self.pageViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PageViewController") as! UIPageViewController
        self.pageViewController.dataSource = self
        let startVC = self.viewControllerAtIndex(0) as ContentViewController
        let viewControllers = NSArray(object: startVC)

        self.pageViewController.setViewControllers(viewControllers as? [UIViewController], direction: .Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
        self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height)

        self.addChildViewController(self.pageViewController)
        self.view.addSubview(self.pageViewController.view)
        self.pageViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.forecastService.delegateForecast = self
        print("contained load")
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func viewControllerAtIndex(index: Int) -> ContentViewController{

        if(self.pageDates.count == 0) || (index >= self.pageDates.count){  //MARK2: ---ERRON IN THIS LINE "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb)
            return ContentViewController()
        }

        let vc: ContentViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ContentViewController") as! ContentViewController

        vc.pageIndex = index
        vc.dateText = self.pageDates[index] as! String
        vc.highTmp = self.pageHighTemps[index] as! String
        vc.lowTmp = self.pageLowTemps[index] as! String
        vc.descText = self.pageDescriptions[index] as! String
        //vc.weatherFile = self.pageImages[index] as! String

        return vc
    }
    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        let vc = viewController as! ContentViewController
        var index = vc.pageIndex as Int
        if (index == 0 || index == NSNotFound){
            return nil
        }
        index--
        return self.viewControllerAtIndex(index)
    }

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        let vc = viewController as! ContentViewController
        var index = vc.pageIndex as Int
        if (index == NSNotFound){
            return nil
        }
        index++
        if (index == self.pageDates.count){
            return nil
        }
        return self.viewControllerAtIndex(index)
    }

    func presentationCountForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        return self.pageDates.count
    }

    func presentationIndexForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        return 0
    }
}
```

[When I run the app I get this screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqrwA.png)

and on my output window there's nowhere anything about "forecast loaded" or "dates set", but there's "contained load" (which is under `viewDidLoad` func):

```
self.weatherService.delegate = self **** at main
from DefaultsSet: Los Angeles
Weather Service class city: Los Angeles
Date: 21 Feb 2016 , High: 20.6 °C , Low: 10.0 °C, Text: Clear
Date: 22 Feb 2016 , High: 28.3 °C , Low: 12.8 °C, Text: Sunny
Date: 23 Feb 2016 , High: 27.8 °C , Low: 12.2 °C, Text: Partly Cloudy
Set Weather main view
did forecast pass to delegate?
contained load
```

---

***The reason behind this mess***

I want when the user press Set City button to be able to select a city and then the data from JSON to be parsed on the `MainViewController` (*Current Conditions*) and on the `PageViewController` inside the the `containedVC` (*Forecast for the following days*).

So my thinking is

1. User sets city
2. `WeatherService` is called and pass all the data to `MainViewController`
3. On `setWeather` func on `MainViewController` we set the label on MainViewController
4. On `setForecast` func on `MainViewController` we pass data to the `containedVC` and create the pages dynamically.

but it seems the data never arrive on the `containedVC`. **Any reasons for that?**

Furthermore I can load data to `containedVC` if I make it a `WeatherServiceDelegate` and on viewDidLoad call `setWeather(city: String)` but this way I have to set the city again and not automatically load the data on `Set City` button pressed.

Comment: where is the code for jumping to ContainedViewController ?

Comment: @Pushpa What do you mean? I  create the 'containedVC' inside the function 'setForecast'

Comment: i mean from which controller the containedVC is opening(Push or Present).

Comment: @Pushpa I only have 2 view controllers. MainViewController and the containedVC. The MainViewController creates the containedVC with Storyboard ID.

Answer (score 0):

The time at which you call the delegate, actually the delegate was not set(i.e. delegate is nil).

From my understanding, you just need to pass the data from parent viewController to child for which you could just pass the data through a variable instead of using delegate, as shown below,

```
func createContainer(){
  let controller: UIViewController = (storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("containedVC"))! as UIViewController
  controller.data = forecast // like this
  controller.view.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: self.view.frame.height-220, width: self.view.frame.width-40, height: 200)
  view.addSubview(controller.view)
  self.addChildViewController(controller)
```

}

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I have a question. Do I have to set a variable called `data` inside `ContainedViewController` class? Furthermore if I have understood delegates right I call the delegate with `self.forecastService.delegateForecast = self` on the `override func viewDidLoad` inside `ContainedViewController` class. Am I right? How can be `delegate = nil`  as I set it before I create the `containedVC` on the `MainViewController`

Comment: 1.yes, you need to have a var data in ContainedViewController class
2. if you look at your code you are calling the delegate, even before creating the ContainedViewController class. So there is noway that viewDidLoad() of ContainedViewController class is called which in turn implies you have not set the delegate yet.

Comment: 2.I changed to  `func setForecast(forecast: Forecast) {
             createContainer()
             self.delegateForecast?.loadOnContained(forecast)
        }`    but nothing happens. 1. when i put var controller.data = forecast it gives me error `Value of type 'UIViewController' has no member 'data'` even if I have on `ContainedViewController` class implemented `var data = Forecast(highTemps: [""], lowTemps: [""], dates: [""], descriptionsArray: [""])` **(I deleted `createVC()` and copied the code under `func setForecast(forecast: Forecast)`**

Comment: you cant call a delegate from a parent to child. You have only 2 options,
1.Use a property and pass value from parent to child, which is the simplest way.
2. If you have specific reason to use a delegate, you need to call the delegate from child to parent, and get the required data.

Comment: 1) I'm sorry but I can't follow you here. 2) I use the delegation pattern that I used to transfer data from `WeatherServic`e class to `MainViewController` but that time I started the transfering when a button is pressed and not automatically. To make it more clear I want `containedVC` to show up only when there are data to populate it (forecast struct)